# What is the proper way to format a formula field so that it is properly spaced

Tags: formula-field, syntax-highlighting

I have a formula field that I created: Career__c + ( FOOO__c ).

I want the output of the field to look like: "Ihsan Singh (12345)", but instead, it is looking like this: Service Field Technician334643.

I would appreciate any feedback and suggestions that would help me get the outcome I am seeking.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Spacing and parenthesis in the formula itself are mostly about making the formula itself easy for people to read.

To achieve what you're looking for, you need to use more string concatenation (either `+` or `&`). You only get the spaces that you explicitly add yourself.

`Career__c + " (" + Foo__c + ")"`